# Shell command to add double quotes for number surrounded by dots in property keys

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have following property keys

```
connection.party= 0.0.0.0
remote.app.328.port= 5432
remote.server.url="https://someurl.com?q=78.78"
remote.conncetion.7="basic"
remote.52.base= "local"
level1.34access23="true"
88.location.code=24
location.234.code.52=24
```

I need this converted into following

```
connection.party= 0.0.0.0
remote.app."328".port= 5432
remote.server.url="https://someurl.com?q=78.78"
remote.conncetion."7"="basic"
remote."52".base= "local"
level1.34access23="true"
"88".location.code=24
location."234".code."52"=24
```

all digits in nested property keys which have pre or post or both dot signs need to have double quotes.
Numbers joined with texts in keys should not be updated. (level1.34access23="true" => no change )
Values cannot be updated.

I tried with following , but it add double quotes to all.

```
sed -E 's/^([^=]+)\.([0-9]+)/\1."\2"/' input.properties
```

Can someone please help ?

Comment: You're example excludes the 1 problematic case - `foo.17.18.bar=whatever`. That's a problem because the obvious approach is to replace `\.[0-9]+\.` with `."\1".` but that would consume the `.` between 17 and 18 when processing 17 so it'd fail to process 18 (on the same pass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression obviously fails to require a dot after the number, too, and does not match numbers at the beginning of the expression.

Here is a simple script which anchors numbers with dots on both sides, and keeps on substituting as long as there are still unquoted numbers before the equals sign.

```
sed -E -e 's/^([0-9]+)\./"\1"./' \
    -e :b -e 's/^([^=]+)\.([0-9]+)\./\1."\2"./' -e tb \
    -e 's/^([^=]+)\.([0-9]+)=/\1."\2"=/' input.properties
```

In some more detail,

- Match and substitute a single number before the first dot.

  ```
  s/^([0-9]+)\./"\1"./
  ```
- Declare a label for looping

  ```
  :b
  ```
- Match and substitute numbers between dots

  ```
  s/^([^=]+)\.([0-9]+)\./\1."\2"./
  ```
- If we performed a substitution, loop back to the label

  ```
  tb
  ```

  This ensures that we keep going as long as there are still numbers which require quoting.
- Finally, handle a number immediately before the equals sign.

  ```
  s/^([^=]+)\.([0-9]+)=/\1."\2"=/
  ```

If you are having trouble getting this to run, try putting the entire script in single quotes:

```
sed -E -e 's/^([0-9]+)\./"\1"./
:b 
  s/^([^=]+)\.([0-9]+)\./\1."\2"./
  tb
  s/^([^=]+)\.([0-9]+)=/\1."\2"=/' input.properties
```

As you can see, `sed` is pretty much a write-only language. Here is a simple Awk script which implements the same logic.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="=" }
{ n = split($1, a, "."); f=""
  for(i=1; i<=n; ++i)
    f = (f ? f "." : "") (a[i] ~ /^[0-9]+$/ ? "\"" a[i] "\"" : a[i])
  $1 = f}1' input.properties
```

This is somewhat condensed, too, but it's not too hard to wrap your head around (and if you think it's too obscure, Awk makes it easier to write things out in longhand).

- Before we start processing any input, set the input field separator `FS` and the output field separator `OFS` to an equals sign.

  ```
  BEGIN { FS=OFS="=" }
  ```

  This causes `$1` to contain everything before the first equals sign, and `$2`, `$3`, etc to contain subsequent equals-delimited fields.

  Then, for each input line
- Split the first field `$1` (i.e. everything before the first equals sign) on dots into the array `a`. The length of the array is in `n`.

  ```
  { n = split($1, a, ".");
  ```
- Create an empty string variable `f` where we will be accumulating the replacement value for `$1`.

  ```
  f=""
  ```
- Loop over the fields in `a`, i.e. from 1 through `n`:

  ```
  for(i=1; i<=n; ++i)
  ```
- In the loop, update `f` with additional text.

  - If `f` is non-empty, append a dot after the value of `f`; otherwise, just keep an empty string, concatenated with ...

    ```
    f = (f ? f "." : "")
    ```

    This uses the tertiary operator `(expression ? value : othervalue)` which produces `value` if `expression` is true, otherwise `othervalue`. So, in other words, if `f` is non-empty, yield the concatenation of the current value of `f` and a literal dot `"."`; otherwise, yield an empty string.
  - ... concatenated with the result of another tertiary expression, which yields `a[i]` with or without double quotes, depending on whether it is entirely numerical.

    ```
    (a[i] ~ /^[0-9]+$/ ? "\"" a[i] "\"" : a[i])
    ```
- After looping over the values, `f` will contain the previous value of `$1` but with any all-numeric fields from `a` with double quotes around them. Assign this back to `$1`.

  ```
  $1 = f
  ```
- Finally, print the modified line.

  ```
  }1
  ```

  The closing brace terminates the action we have been performing for every input line, and the ´1` is just a simple idiom which causes Awk to print every line.

  (In some more detail, the value `1` is applied as a condition, which is always true, with no action, which implies the default action, which is to print the current input record.)

Comment: I just ran, but I got: 
sed: can't find label for jump to `b' . Am I doing something wrong..

Comment: There are unfortunately some common portability issues around the syntax of labels. I tested this on MacOS but you are apparently on a different platform. I'll add a variant which should work more portably.

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  s1="\""
  FS=OFS="="
}
{
  first=$1
  while(match(first,/(\.|^)([0-9]+)(\.|$)/,arr)){
    sub(arr[2],s1 arr[2] s1,$1)
    first=substr($1,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Would you please try the following:

```
sed -E 's/^([^=]+\.)?([0-9]+)(\.|=)/\1"\2"\3/' input.properties
```

- `^([^=]+\.)?` matches zero or one sequence of any characters other
  than an equal sign followed by a dot. The `zero` case will make
  match the leading number such as `88`.
- `(\.|=)` matches a following dot or equal sign.

**[Edit]**

If `perl` happens to be your choice, how about:

```
perl -pe 's/(^|\.)(\d+)(?=\.|=)(?=.*=)/$1"$2"/g' input.properties
```

which will work if the key contains multiple numbers in the key.

- `(^|\.)` matches the beginning of the string or a dot and the matched
  substring is referred by `$1` as a backreference (as `\1` does in sed).
- `(\d+)` matches a number.
- `(?=\.|=)` is a positive lookahead which matches a dot or an equal sign
  without incrementing the search position of regex.
- `(?=.*=)` is a positive lookahead which matches a sequence of any
  characters followed by an equal sign. It ensures the replacement
  occurs only within the key.
- The `g` option enables multiple replacements.

Comment: Thank you. Yes. it worked. but I wonder what if the key has 2 numbers - location.234.code.52=24 (expected location."234".code."52"=24. this will only add quotes to one number only. (Yes, initial question doesn't have this scenario). May I know how I can improve this to support for it also ?

Comment: This snag illuminates the need for your question to contain all the corner cases you actually want to handle, going forward.

Comment: @tshiono, ++ve for nice answer, thanks for sharing. Is it GNU `sed` specific just asking, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thank you for the attention, but my code is not so good so far because it doesn't consider the possible case OP added as a comment.  BTW the code should be compatible with POSIX sed. Cheers.

Comment: @tshiono, answers are always given as per question only so you are spot on :) Even my answer in GNU `awk` is as per question only cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are okay with python

```
"""
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76320083/shell-command-to-add-double-quotes-for-number-surrounded-by-dots-in-property-key

$ cat /tmp/a
connection.party= 0.0.0.0
remote.app.328.port= 5432
remote.server.url="https://someurl.com?q=78.78"
remote.conncetion.7="basic"
remote.52.base= "local"
level1.34access23="true"
88.location.code=24
location.234.code.52=24 
"""

import re

with open("/tmp/a", "r") as reader:
    for line in reader.readlines():
        sline = line.split("=")
        m = re.sub(r"(^|\.)(\d+)(\.|$)", r"\1" + '"' + r"\2" + '"' + r"\3", sline[0])
        print("=".join([m, sline[1].strip()]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for `gensub()`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="=" }
{
    for (i=1; i<=2; i++) {
        $1 = gensub(/(^|\.)([0-9]+)(\.|$)/,"\\1\"\\2\"\\3","g",$1)
    }
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
connection.party= 0.0.0.0
remote.app."328".port= 5432
remote.server.url="https://someurl.com?q=78.78"
remote.conncetion."7"="basic"
remote."52".base= "local"
level1.34access23="true"
"88".location.code=24
location."234".code."52"=24
foo."17"."18".bar=whatever
```

or using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="=" }
{
    while ( match($1,/(^|\.)[0-9]+(\.|$)/) ) {
        tgt = substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        sub(/^\.?/,"&\"",tgt)
        sub(/\.?$/,"\"&",tgt)
        $1 = substr($1,1,RSTART-1) tgt substr($1,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
connection.party= 0.0.0.0
remote.app."328".port= 5432
remote.server.url="https://someurl.com?q=78.78"
remote.conncetion."7"="basic"
remote."52".base= "local"
level1.34access23="true"
"88".location.code=24
location."234".code."52"=24
foo."17"."18".bar=whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents:

```
sed 's/=/\n/' | \
  sed '/./ {s/\([0-9][0-9]*\)/"\1"/g;N;s/\n/=/;}' input.properties
```

The first `sed` splits a property and its value in 2 lines.

The second one surrounds the numbers with `"` char in the first line (property name) and concatenates the value (from the second line).

Behavior won't be the one expected if there are values over several lines: the command line must found the property and its value on the same unique line.

Answer (score 1):

no capturing groups necessary

```
     1  connection.party= 0.0.0.0
     2  remote.app.328.port= 5432
     3  remote.server.url="https://someurl.com?q=78.78"
     4  remote.conncetion.7="basic"
     5  remote.52.base= "local"
     6  level1.34access23="true"
     7  88.location.code=24
     8  location.234.code.52=24
```

---

```
  mawk 'gsub("(^|[.])[0-9]+([.]|$)", ".\"\3&\5\".",
             $!_) gsub("[.]*($|[\3\5][.]*)|^[.]",_, $!_)' FS== OFS==
```

---

```
     1  connection.party= 0.0.0.0
     2  remote.app."328".port= 5432
     3  remote.server.url="https://someurl.com?q=78.78"
     4  remote.conncetion."7"="basic"
     5  remote."52".base= "local"
     6  level1.34access23="true"
     7  "88".location.code=24
     8  location."234".code."52"=24
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}
    { 
      for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if(match($i, /[^0-9]=/)) break
        if(match($i, /^[0-9]+$|^[0-9]*=/)) sub(/^[0-9]+/,"\"&\"", $i)
      }
    }1
' file

connection.party= 0.0.0.0
remote.app."328".port= 5432
remote.server.url="https://someurl.com?q=78.78"
remote.conncetion."7"="basic"
remote."52".base= "local"
level1.34access23="true"
"88".location.code=24
location."234".code."52"=24
```